# How do I run C# code that's in a textfile from another C# app

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, console

So I have this textfile that looks like this, and I'd like to create a console application that reads the content of it and invokes the "Main" method.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried doing this using [CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) but the issue there is that I would have to add it as a dependency to the project since I'm using `.NET 6` and I would prefer to do it without having to add any extra dependencies.

The only thing I have so far is that I read the content of the textfile, but I have no idea how to invoke the "Main" method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var code = File.ReadAllLines("csharpcode.txt");

}
```

How do I properly invoke the `Main` method from my application by reading code from a textfile?

Comment: Tell the csharp compiler (csc.exe) to compile it and run the resulting exe? What sort of control do you want over the process? How often do you rewrite the file? How many times will you run the code before you write a new variant of it?

Comment: Have you looked at anything like https://laurentkempe.com/2019/02/18/dynamically-compile-and-run-code-using-dotNET-Core-3.0/ or https://blog.dominikasikorska.pl/compiling-c-sharp-code-at-runtime/ ? Let us know what you try and exactly how it doesn't work out, if it doesnt

Comment: There is an old [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2160/Runtime-C-Expression-Evaluator) from 2002 which shows how to compile and execute C# in-memory.